# Does QStringList have performance gain when allocating memory?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

Is there any performance gain if we allocate memory for `QStringList`?

```
const size_t size = 10;
QStringList myList;
myList.reserve(size);
```

I understand its use for `QVector<QString>` but not for `QList`.

Comment: `QStringList` is a `QList<QString>`. You may read about `QList`. Anyway, each new `QString` instance do a self allocation. You have a real problems with performance of `QStringList`?

Comment: @AlexF Thanks. I got it. I thought  it is implemented as linkedlist.

Comment: @SumitJha this article https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity can be helpful for you